# Как написать скрипт на python, для управления сайтом?

Tags: python

есть сайт, на котором, мне нужно выполнять действия. Нужно написать скрипт, чтобы эти действия он выполнял сам. без меня. например:

- нужно зайти туда
- выбрать это
- потом перейти сюда
- нажать это

и т.д.
как это можно реализовать? может быть библиотека есть какая нибудь?
и библиотека, которая двигает курсор не подходит.

Comment: Нужно просто загуглить и перейти по первой ссылке. `Selenium`

Answer (score 1):

есть модуль PyAutoGUI
с помощью него можно управлять курсором надо только поставить определенные координаты и сказать что бы он нажал на эту точку. Библиотеку можно использовать не только для сайта но я для того что бы писать текст за вас.
вот простой пример

```
import pyautogui as pg

# Получение позиции мыши и вывод в консоль
print(pg.position())

# Передвижение мыши
pg.move(50, 50, duration=0.5)
pg.moveTo('координаты') # Передвигаем к точке относительно экрана

# Нажатие мышкой по определенной точке
pg.click('координаты')
pg.doubleclick(769, 101) # двойное нажатие
pg.rightclick(769, 101) # нажатие правой кнопкой мыши
pg.leftclick(769, 101) # нажатие левой кнопкой мыши
# Ввод текста
pg.typewrite("ваш текст")
# Выполнения нажатия на клавишу
pg.typewrite(["enter"])
```

если помогло то сделайте этот ответ правильным

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос очень общий и не описывает конкретную проблему, поэтому и ответ Вам можно дать только общий.  
  Есть разные модули которые решают разные задачи, например, посмотрите   https://pypi.org/project/requests/ или https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ 
  Не забывайте, что Вы можете не только, воспроизводить действия пользователя, например: открыть сайт, нажать на окно ввода логин, ввести логин и т.д., но и в коде уже передавать нужные значения, например с помощью того же https://pypi.org/project/requests/